# How do I prove this combinatorial identity using inclusion and exclusion principle?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

$$\binom{n}{m}-\binom{n}{m+1}+\binom{n}{m+2}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-m}\binom{n}{n}=\binom{n-1}{m-1}$$
Note that we can show this with out using inclusion and exclusion principle by using Pascal's Identity i.e. $C(n,k)=C(n-1,k)+C(n-1,k-1)$.

Comment: I'm really puzzled by this question, but I like it. Do you have some motivation for it? I'll write an extended comment in the answer section, but I wanted first to ask you this.

Comment: I was doing it from a book on Combinatorics of Inclusion and exclusion principle chapter. I was able to do some of its problems. But this one was too difficult. Some more questions like this (particularly on inclusion and exclusion principle) are also there of same level of difficulty. @PedroSánchezTerraf

Comment: @JishuDas: May I ask which book are you using?

Comment: It is a book on Combinatorial Techniques by Sharad S. Sane. [Combinatorial Techniques](http://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Techniques-Texts-Readings-Mathematics/dp/9380250487) This link may help you. @BillMoustakas

Comment: One idea I had is not to take the obvious expression of In-Ex principle here (by considering just $n-m+1$ sets), but one may take a bigger family of sets, for which intersections of more than $n-m+1$ sets among them vanish. Perhaps using this  a better combinatorial approach could be found.

Comment: I would consider experimenting with binomial theorem $((1+1)^m - (1-1)^n)$ or similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, that's why I'm putting it here.

The first observation is that your formula already implies Pascal's identity. Replacing $m$ by $m+1$ we have
$$\binom{n}{m+1}-\binom{n}{m+2}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-m-1}\binom{n}{n}=\binom{n-1}{m}.$$
Adding to the original formula gives (after cancelling) $\binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1}=\binom{n}{m}$. So, in some sense, any proof of this identity must include some idea proving Pascal's.

Now there is a way to putting the LHS as an application of Inclusion-Exclusion principle. Take the following sets:

$$
\begin{align}
A_1 &:= \left\{1,2,\dots,\textstyle\binom{n-1}{m-1}\right\}\\
A_2 &:= \left\{1,2,\dots,\textstyle\binom{n-2}{m-1}\right\}\\
 &\dots \\
A_{n-m+1} &:= \left\{\textstyle\binom{m-1}{m-1}\right\} =\{1\}.
\end{align}
$$
So we have $A_1\supset A_2 \supset \dots \supset A_{n-m+1}$. If you apply In-Ex to prove that 
$$
|A_1\cup \dots \cup A_{n-m+1}| = |A_1|=\textstyle\binom{n-1}{m-1},
$$
you may obtain (through extensive use of Pascal's and perhaps also induction) the summation on the LHS of your equation.

Comment: This turned out to be a good idea!

Comment: Thanks, I'll count that as a +1 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Expanded from Pedro Sánchez Terraf's answer, but added my view to write a more combinatorial proof.

Viewing the diagonals of the Pascal's triangle, recall that $\binom {m+n-1} m$ represents the $n$'th $m$-dimensional simplex number. (Ones for $0$-dimension, natural numbers for $1$-dimension, then triangle numbers, tetrahedral numbers, pentatope numbers, etc.) (e.g. $\binom {n+1} 2$ represents the $n$'th triangle number)

With fixed $m$ and $n$, let $A_i$ be the set of integers from $1$ to $\binom {(m-1)+i-1}{m-1}$, $i = 1 \ldots (n-m+1)$:
$$\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \left\{1, \ldots, \binom {m-1}{m-1}\right\} = \left\{1\right\}\\
A_2 &= \left\{1, 2, \ldots, \binom{m}{m-1}\right\}\\
&= \left\{1, 2, \ldots,\binom m1\right\}\\
&= \left\{1, 2, \ldots, m\right\}\\
&\vdots\\
A_i &= \left\{1, 2, \ldots, \binom{m+i-2}{m-1}\right\}\\
&\vdots\\
A_{n-m+1} &= \left\{1, 2, \ldots, \binom{(m-1)+(n-m+1)-1}{m-1}\right\}\\
&= \left\{1, 2, \ldots, \binom {n-1}{m-1}\right\}\\\\
\end{align*}$$
Call the number of sets, and also the number of terms, $n-m+1$, be $N$.

**Edit added:** In hindsight, $A_{n-m+1}$'s may as well be sets of balls that form the $(n-m+1)$th simplex in $m$ dimension. All the other $A_i$'s are the set of balls that form smaller $m$-simplexes of size $i$, are subset of $A_{n-m+1}$, and share the same vertex.

---

For the right hand side, the union of all these sets is
$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}A_i\right| = \left|A_{N}\right| = \binom {n-1}{m-1}$$

---

For the left hand side, the first term,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left|A_i\right| =& \sum_{i=1}^{N} \binom{m+i-2}{m-1} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^{N} \binom{(m-1)+i-1}{m-1}\\
=& \binom{m + N -1}{m}\\
=& \binom{n}{m}
\end{align*}$$
The second-to-last step comes from the definition that, the sum of the $1$st to the $N$'th simplex number is the $N$'th simplex number of the next dimension.

---

For each of the later term, say the $k$'th, out of the $N$ sets, each time $k$ of the sets have their set intersection taken and added. ($1 \le k \le N = n-m+1$)

There are $\binom{N-1}{k-1}$ sets that contain $A_1$, and the size of each of those intersections will be $1 = \binom{m-1}{m-1}$. Then there are $\binom{N-2}{k-1}$ sets that contain $A_2$ but not $A_1$, etc. Summing the count of those intersections with their respective sizes, the $k$'th term on the left hand side of OP's formula is
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N-(k-1)}\binom{m+i-2}{m-1}\binom{N-i}{k-1}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N-k+1}\binom{(m-1)+i-1}{m-1}\binom{(k-1)+(N-k+2-i)-1}{k-1}
\end{align*}$$
Each of the two binomial coefficients is a sequence of hyper-tetrahedral number. The second binomial coefficient, $\binom{N-i}{k-1}$ runs from $\binom{N-1}{k-1}=\binom{(k-1)+(N-k+1)-1}{k-1}$ back to $\binom{k-1}{k-1} = \binom{(k-1)+1-1}{k-1}$. When viewed as a term-by-term product of two sequences of tetrahedral numbers, the result is another tetrahedral number of higher dimension:
$$\binom{n}{m+k-1}$$

**See edited below** <strike>But this is just my intuition and I have yet to fully proved this.</strike>

---

The summation is consistent with the last two terms in OP's formula:

when $k = N-1 = n-m$, the summation consists of two terms,
$$\begin{align*}\binom {m-1}{m-1}\binom{N-1}{N-2}
+ \binom {m}{m-1}\binom{N-2}{N-2}
& =(N-1)+m\\
&= n \\
&=\binom{n}{n-1}
\end{align*}$$
which confirms that are $N-1=n-m$ intersections each with $1$ element, and  $A_2\cap A_3 \cap \cdots \cap A_N$ which has $m$ elements.

when $k = N = n-m+1$, the summation consists of one term, 
$$\binom {m-1}{m-1}\binom{N-1}{N-1}=1=\binom{n}{n}$$
which also confirms that the intersection of $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{n-m+1}$ has only one element.

---

**Edit:** To prove:
$$\sum_{i=1}^c\binom {a+i-1}a \binom{b+(c+1-i)-1}b = \binom{(a+b+1)+c-1}{a+b+1}$$
I have added extra parentheses and terms so that each binomial coefficient can be translated directly to a simplex number with specific dimension.

First, the summation introduces 1 dimension. Call this the $x$-direction.

Second, consider $\binom{a+i-1}a$ only. Each term itself is the $i$th simplex number in $a$-dimension. Extend the 1-dimensional world to $1+a$ dimension world, with new orthogonal directions $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_a$.

Then for each of the $c$ terms, arrange $\binom{a+i-1}a$ balls in the simplex shape in the new $a$ dimensions, in an integer grid of origin $(1,1,1,\ldots, 1)$. The simplex is right-angled with $a+1$ vertices at $(y_1, y_2,y_3, \ldots, y_a) =$
$$(1,1,1,\ldots, 1),\ 
(i, 1, 1, \ldots, 1),\ 
(1, i, 1, \ldots, 1),\ 
(1, 1, i, \ldots, 1),\ldots,\ 
(1, 1, 1, \ldots, i)$$

Stack the $c$ simplexes along $x$-direction, by putting the $i$th simplex at $x=i$. This stack of sequential simplexes gives an $(a+1)$-simplex of vertices at
$(x; y_1, y_2,y_3, \ldots, y_a)=$
$$(c; 1,1,1,\ldots, 1),\ 
(c;c, 1, 1, \ldots, 1),\ 
(c;1, c, 1, \ldots, 1),\ 
(c;1, 1, c, \ldots, 1),\ldots,\ 
(c;1, 1, 1, \ldots, c)$$
and the origin $(1;1,1,1,\ldots,1)$

Third, again, extend the world from $1+a$ dimensions to $1+a+b$ dimensions, calling the new $b$ orthogonal directions as $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_b$.

For each ball previously on the $x=i$ slice, the number has to be multiplied by $\binom{b+(c+1-i)-1}b$, which is the $(c+1-i)$th simplex number in $b$ dimension. Arrange $\binom{b+(c+1-i)-1}b$ balls in a $b$-simplex shape with right angle at the origin $(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_b) = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)$. Copy this simplex for every ball on the $x=i$ slice. Repeat this for every slice on the $x$-direction, and the new simplex is finished, with dimension $a+b+1$.

The new simplex has vertices at $(x; y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_a; z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_b)=$

- The origin:
  $(1;1,1,\ldots,1;1,1,\ldots,1)$
- To $x$-direction: $(c;1,1,\ldots,1;1,1,\ldots,1)$
- To $y$-direcions:
  $$(c;c, 1, \ldots, 1;1,1,\ldots,1),\ 
  (c;1, c, \ldots, 1;1,1,\ldots,1),\ldots,\ 
  (c;1, 1, 1, \ldots, c;1,1,\ldots,1)$$
- To $z$-directions:
  $$(1;1, 1, \ldots, 1;c,1,\ldots,1),\ 
  (1;1, 1, \ldots, 1;1,c,\ldots,1),\ldots,\ 
  (1;1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1;1,1,\ldots,c)$$

Notice that for the $y$-directions, the simplex is sheared, and the vertices are not on the "axes" where all but one coordinates are $1$. However, by shearing along every $y$ directions, it is possible to obtain a scaled standard simplex.

And lastly, the number of balls in the $c$th $(a+b+1)$-simplex is $\binom{(a+b+1)+c-1}{a+b+1}$. Substitute $a= m-1$, $b=k-1$, $c=n-m+1$.

*And by balls, I mean hyperspheres.*

---

An example of how balls are stacked, $a=2$, $b=2$, $c=4$, which results in a $5$-simplex. The simplex arrangement is sliced perpendicular to $x$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ directions.

[image: Example]

Comment: Yeah, that summation is the nut to crack...

Comment: So what I have added, based on your solution, is the combinatorial idea of counting tetrahedral numbers. @PedroSánchezTerraf

Comment: Have my vote, at least one of us deserves the bounty!

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin by rewriting the formula with a shift from $n$ and $m$ to $n+1$ and $m+1$, so that the expression to prove is

$${n\choose m} = {n+1\choose m+1}-{n+1\choose m+2}+{n+1\choose m+3}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-m}{n+1\choose n+1}$$

Now picture a class with $n$ students and a teacher.  Each term on the right is of the form ${n+1\choose k}$, which counts the number of ways you can choose a group of size $k$ from among the $n+1$ people in the class.  Among these groups are some that include the teacher and some that don't.  Each group of size $k$ that *doesn't* include the teacher can be identified with a group of size $k+1$ that *does* include the teacher.

The expression ${n\choose m}$ can be interpreted as counting the number of ways you can choose a group of size $m$ from among the $n$ students only -- and then, if you like, adding the teacher to get a group of size $m+1$.  The inclusion-exclusion is now clear:  Start with *all* the ways you can form a group of size $m+1$, then try to eliminate the overcount, which consists of the all-student groups.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It is simple to understand, but I am not sure how to choose sets $A_1,\cdots,A_r$ to justify it formally using the formula for the IE principle.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer is inspired by the deleted answer of @diracpaul.

We  analyze lattice paths generated from $(1,0)$ steps in $x$-direction  and $(0,1)$ steps in $y$-direction. The number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n-m)$  is $\binom{n}{m}$. This is valid since for paths of length $n$ we can select $m$ steps in $x$-direction leaving $n-m$ steps in $y$-direction.

Let's write $\binom{n}{m}$ in the more symmetrical version using *[multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)* $\binom{n}{m,n-m}$. Using this notation OPs equation becomes

\begin{align*}
\binom{n-1}{m-1,n-m}&=\binom{n}{m,n-m}-\binom{n}{m+1,n-m-1}\\
&\qquad+\binom{n}{m+2,n-m-2}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-m}\binom{n}{n,0}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> For convenience only we change the representation by setting $x=m$ and $y=n-m$. Then OPs equation (1) becomes
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}&=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y}{x+1,y-1}\\
> &\qquad+\binom{x+y}{x+2,y-2}-\cdots+(-1)^{y}\binom{x+y}{x+y,0}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Before we interpret the identity (2) one additional aspect. We can use only $(1,0)$ steps or $(0,1)$ steps. So, when we go from $(0,0)$ to a point $(x,y)$ with $x,y>0$, we have to pass either $(x-1,y)$ or $(x,y-1)$. This gives the well known identity

\begin{align*}
\binom{x+y}{x,y}=\binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}+\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Now we claim the following:
>
> - The LHS of (2) gives the number of paths of length $x+y-1$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x-1,y)$.
> - The RHS of (2) gives the number of paths of length $x+y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ which pass $(x-1,y)$.
>
> Since there is only one possibility to go from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ via $(x-1,y)$, namely by adding a $(1,0)$ step from $(x-1,y)$ to $(x,y)$ it's obvious that both parts give the same number. According to (3) we conclude
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}&=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> The RHS of expression (4) is correct, but not the same as the RHS of (3).
>
> The idea is to approach the representation (3) step by step. We note that $\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}$ is the number of paths of length $x+y-1$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y-1)$.  We argue now similar as above and say that this is the same as the number of paths of length $x+y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x+1,y-1)$ *passing through* $(x,y-1)$.
>
> This is realised according to (3) via
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}&=\binom{x+y}{x+1,y-1}-\binom{x+y-1}{x+1,y-2}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> Combining this with (4) gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}&=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}\\
> &=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y}{x+1,y-1}+\binom{x+y-1}{x+1,y-2}
> \end{align*}
>
> And again we substitute the surplus $\binom{x+y-1}{x+1,y-2}$ by the number of pathes of length $x+y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x+2,y-2)$ *passing through* $(x+1,y-2)$. This results in
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}&=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}\\
> &=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y}{x+1,y-1}+\binom{x+y}{x+2,y-2}-\binom{x+y-1}{x+2,y-3}
> \end{align*}

Proceeding in this way we finally reach step by step the RHS of (2). Observe that the amounts of surplus are compensated according to the inclusion-exclusion principle.

> We conclude: The binomial identity
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}&=\binom{x+y}{x,y}-\binom{x+y}{x+1,y-1}\\
> &\qquad+\binom{x+y}{x+2,y-2}-\cdots+(-1)^{y}\binom{x+y}{x+y,0}=\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> shows that the number of paths of length $x+y-1$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x-1,y)$ is the same as the number of paths of length $x+y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ passing through $(x-1,y)$, whereby the surplus can be compensated by successively adding and subtracting paths of length $x+y$ according to the inclusion-exclusion principle.